# Url.Action() does not use good route config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have overridden a default route in my routes configuration :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute("MyController_OverriddenAction",
             "MyController/OverriddenAction",
             new { controller = "MyOverriddenController", action = "OverridenAction" },
             new[] { "Plugin" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

If I call `MyController/OverriddenAction`, the overridden action `OverriddenAction` in `MyOverriddenController` is displayed. It works.

But if I call `@Html.Action("OverriddenAction", "MyController")`, the default route is called.

Why? What is the solution?

My controllers :

```
public class MyOverridenController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult OverriddenAction()
    {
        return Content("overridden");
    }
}


public class MyController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult OverriddenAction()
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: please add your MyController here

Comment: I have edited my original post

Answer (score 0):

You should use following syntax

```
 @Html.Action("OverriddenAction", "MyOverriden")
```

while calling the method directly like `MyController/OverriddenAction` it looks for the entry in MapRoute. However, while using `@Html.Action` you should use the actual controller name.

Comment: I can't use this solution because the overriden controller is imported via a plugin (like the maproute configuration)

Comment: I don't understand this behaviour. Why this helper doesn't use the routing ? The problem is the same if the action called is in a different controller...